# How to sum data by column with different name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Have query like this :

```
select [name],count(*) as [count], SUM(balance1) balance1,SUM(balance2) balance2
from mytbl
WHERE [date] between ... --some filters
GROUP BY [name]
```

The result of query is :

**EDITED :**

```
name   balance1    balance2  count
A1      10.00       12.00     10
A2      11.00       20.00     20
A3      9.00        5.00      30
BB1     5.00        2.00      45
BB2     1.00        0.00      50
CCC1    15.00       20.00     23
```

Want group by the letters result must be :

```
name   balance1    balance2   count
A1      10.00       12.00      10
A2      11.00       20.00      20
A3      9.00        5.00       30
SUM     30.00       37.00      60
BB1     5.00        2.00       45
BB2     1.00        0.00       50
SUM     6.00        2.00       95
CCC1    15.00       20.00      23
SUM     15.00       20.00      23
```

**EDITED :**
Sample data : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/977f5/1

How to do it ?

Comment: Make demo using http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data. Probably you need `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`. Also your result query is non the same as query. Where is `COUNT`?

Comment: How to detect groups? Each group starts with 1 in the end of name? Or each groups starts with letter like A, B, C..? Provide sample data.

Comment: @lad2025  I add sqlfiddle for sample data

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas each group start with same name but different numbers in the end

Comment: Should the `A1` and `AA1` be in the same group?

Comment: @lad2025 no it's different groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(name, 'SUM') as name,
       count(*) as [count],
       SUM(balance1) as balance1, SUM(balance2) as balance2
from mytbl
where [date] between ... --some filters
group by grouping sets( (name, left(name, 1)), (left(name, 1)) );
```

(Note:  this uses the lazy short-hand of `coalesce()` for identifying the "SUM" rows.)

Comment: @GeoVIP Keep in mind that in this case `A1` and `AA1` are the same group

Comment: @lad2025 I change left(name, 1) to left(name, 4) this one will always be unique for me. thank you for advice